# Pasting JavaScript onto console; part of the code doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This is my code, which gets the most common words in English from Wikipedia, then collects all the words on the page and filters the most common words from the list of words:

```
// get table data from most common words
var arr = [];
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
})
.done(function(html) {
   var table = $(html).find(".wikitable");
   for(var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
       arr[i - 1] = table[0].rows[i].children[0].innerText;
   }
});

var text = document.getElementById('content').innerText;
var words = text.split(/[^a-zA-Z]/);
//filter empty strings
words = words.filter(Boolean);
//filter single characters
words = words.filter(function(word) {
    return word.length > 1;
});

words = words.filter(function(word) {
    return word !== 'was';
});

words = words.filter(function(word) {
    return word !== 'where';
});

words = words.filter(function(word) {
    return word !== 'is';
});

words = words.filter(function(word) {
    return word !== 'are';
});

// filter stopWords from 100 most common words wikipedia page
words = words.filter(function(word) {
    var isNotStopWord = true;
    var i = 0;
    for(var stopWord in arr) {
        if(word === arr[i++]) {
            isNotStopWord = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isNotStopWord;
});
```

But this last block of code doesn't seem to run:

```
// filter stopWords from 100 most common words wikipedia page
words = words.filter(function(word) {
    var isNotStopWord = true;
    var i = 0;
    for(var stopWord in arr) {
        if(word === arr[i++]) {
            isNotStopWord = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isNotStopWord;
});
```

Unless I paste that part onto the console and run it again?

Comment: Where do you store words in "content"? I see an AJAX function where the A stands for Asynchronous which means the result of the call is not available until AFTER the call, e.g. in the `done` - next time please click the `<>` and post the HTML too

Comment: Also `words = words.filter(function(word) {
    return word.length>1 && stopWords.indexOf(word) ===-1;
});`

Comment: So your complete code is `var stopWords = [];
$.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',function(html) {
   var table = $(html).find(".wikitable");
   for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       stopWords.push(table[0].rows[i].children[0].innerText);
   }
   var text = document.getElementById('content').innerText;
   var words = text.split(/[^a-zA-Z]/);
   words = words.filter(function(word) { return word.length>1 && 
    stopWords.indexOf(word) ===-1; });
    $("#someContainer").append(words.join('<br/>');
});`

Comment: If I declare the words in the function, I can't use it outside the AJAX call. I want to able to use that list of words later on.

Comment: Then define it as a global but you can NOT access it until after the Ajax finishes

Answer (score 0):

that part of code runs even on first time but as arr[] is empty for first time you may not see its effect.
this code should work if you move that piece of code in ajax done method.

```
  var arr = [];
    $.ajax({
       url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
    })
    .done(function(html) {
       var table = $(html).find(".wikitable");
       for(var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
           arr[i - 1] = table[0].rows[i].children[0].innerText;
       }
     words = words.filter(function (element,index){
         return (arr.indexOf(element) === -1)
     })


    console.log(words)

    });

    var text = document.getElementById('content').innerText;
    var words = text.split(/[^a-zA-Z]/);
    //filter empty strings
    words = words.filter(Boolean);
    //filter single characters
    words = words.filter(function(word) {
        return word.length > 1;
    });

    words = words.filter(function(word) {
        return word !== 'was';
    });

    words = words.filter(function(word) {
        return word !== 'where';
    });

    words = words.filter(function(word) {
        return word !== 'is';
    });

    words = words.filter(function(word) {
        return word !== 'are';
    });
```

Comment: I tried moving that block of code into the done function but i'm still seeing the same result. the declaration of text and words also has to be put before the ajax call

Comment: is your ajax call completes? can you check that in network tab?

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/zJ5gc) is my network tab. I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you get any error in console?  I see No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in my console

Comment: I think you have to do the call on a wikipedia page i.e. https://en.wikipedia.com

Comment: I checked it in wiki page and it works fine.I edited one of filter method to reduce line of code.  is it not working for you?

Comment: I got it to work. I had to put the declaration of arr in the ajax call though.

Comment: ideally thats not needed but any ways if it works then nothing like it. enjoy:)